# Fullcalendar EventSource URL not authenticated - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, authentication, fullcalendar

I have added an eventsource to the Fullcalendar in my application. Following is the code for the same.

```
$scope.eventSources = [{
    url: URL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'id': id
    }
}];
```

Though all my request to the server are authenticated, the request through the event source fails in authentication. If I disable the authentication in the server the EventSource works as expected. Is there any reason for the issue?

I have a Node JS server in which authentication is done through PassportJs. I have used req.isAuthenticated() function to verify if the all the request to the server are authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried fetching the events through a function and it worked. Below is the code.

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'start': start,
            'end': end
        }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            //success code
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            //error handler
        });
}
```